# How to disable "BIU" buttons at onscreen keyboard (ipad safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

My page contains text editor based on . Safari`s keyboard contain buttons "BIU" (bold, italic, underline). This buttons damage markup with unnecessary tags <b>, <i>, <u>.
Can i disable this buttons?